# Compose Scala parser combinators

Tags: scala, parsing, functional-programming, combinators

I want to parse a String with scala parser combinators. Lets take

> abcd,123,ghijk

as example. So we have 2 words and an Integer joined by comma.

I can do it like that:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

case class MyObject(field1:String, field2:Integer, field3:String)

object Test3 extends RegexParsers {
    def main(args:Array[String]) {
      val testRow = "abcd,123,ghijk"

      val parseResult = Test3.parse(Test3.myObject, testRow)

      println(parseResult)
    }

    def word = "\\w+".r ^^ { _ toString }
    def int = """\d+""".r ^^ { _ toInt }
    def comma = "," ^^ { _ toString }

    def myObject = word ~ comma ~ int ~ comma ~ word ^^ { 
      case wordfield1 ~ sep1 ~ intfield ~ sep2 ~ wordfield2
      => MyObject(wordfield1, intfield, wordfield2)
    }
}
```

However, I want to use the logic "joined by comma". Therefore rather than explicit writing `word ~ comma ~ int ~ comma ~ word` it should look more like

```
List(word, int, word) someFunctionIDontKnow {
    (resultParser, nextParser) => resultParser ~ comma ~ nextParser
}
```

I am a little stuck here because I'm not sure how to save my parsers (with different types: `Parser[int]` and `Parser[String]`) into a List while maintaining type safety and what function to use to combine these like i did manually. Is what I want even possible or am I on the wrong track here?

Comment: Use the [`repsep`](http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.co.uk/2008/09/scala-parser-combinators.html#repeatedterms) combinator.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thanks, but I am not sure how to use it yet. It seems repsep can be used for repitition of the same parser (separated by another one), but I have different parsers (`word` and `int`) separated by another one (`comma`). How would I use repsep to combine these different parsers?

Comment: `repsep` won't help if you want to keep the types. `~` or a `for`-comprehension really is probably your best bet, unless you want to go all out for a Shapeless-based solution that would let you use tuples (but would involve needing to write some of your own generic code).

Comment: You can `repsep` the `myObject` parser (`repsep(myObject, ",")`) if the pattern repeats itself (i. e `word,int,word,word,int,word,word,int,word,...`), otherwise I'm not sure what you ask is duable in the way you need.

Comment: I see that you ask how to save objects of various types into a single list. What does it hast to do with parser combinators? It looks like you are using parser combinators as the scam stone, which was used by cunning Grimm Brothers to prank villagers and brew them a Stone Soup. Otherwise, clean up your code using `extends App with Parsers` instead of `def main`, `"," ~> int` to drop the punctuation and ready-made `int` and `ident` words in the JavaTokenParsers. I think that `"".r` parsers produce string already, which you assume by applying `_.toInt`.